# Waterline ORM - check if an array attribute contains values

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I have a model with these attributes:

```
  attributes: {
    title: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    tags: {
        type: 'array'
    }
  }
```

How can I query whether or not the `tags` attribute contains some value? For example, I would like to select all the records that have the tags `blue` and `green`.
Is this even possible with Waterline? I couldn't find any documentation regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waterline doesn't support the array type in this manner. The proper way do check if a record has some values is use an association. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717628/how-to-use-the-attribute-type-like-array-and-json-in-sails?rq=1) from stack overflow. See Sails documentation on associations: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html

Comment: I encountered a similar scenario where a given model contained the attribute `activities`. An array consisting of only strings. Even worse, `activities` of different instances of the model aren't overlapping. It wouldn't make any sense to create an own model for these `activities`, so using associations is not an real option in this case. Is there another way of querying model instances by whether or an array contains a value?